# Why is "apples are good to be eaten" incorrect?

Tags: passive-voice, infinitives, exam-questions, active-vs-passive

I was doing an online test where they asked to fill in the blank.
Here's the question:

> Apples are good ______

Here are the choices:

> 1. to be eating
> 2. to eat
> 3. to eating
> 4. to be eaten

I selected "to be eaten" because it's, for me, grammatically correct.
However, I was incorrect.

I was searching for similar questions and found [this question on
Brainly](https://brainly.in/question/8070433) that suggests "to be eaten" is incorrect.

So, why is "apples are good to be eaten" incorrect?

Comment: _Good to eat_ is the usual way we describe a tasty food. Eating the apples is what we consider 'good'. Being eaten is what the apples 'experience'.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a particularly good exam question because there are ways of understanding the word "good" such that your "to be eaten" is perfectly acceptable. For example, if "good" is taken to mean "ready", as in *"Are you good to go?"* then your choice works. Or, if "good" means "able to be relied upon", as in *"Is Mugsie good for the ten thousand dollars?"* then your choice also works.

However, both of those uses are informal, so depending on the type of exam it may have been expected that you would know not to allow for those interpretations.

Still, if it's any consolation, your choice suggests than you may have a better grasp of idiomatic English than whomever set that exam.